# Finding a small bmp file in a bigger bmp file

Tags: c++, bmp

I want to find a small bmp file from another bigger bmp file (the bigger one is captured from screen and called Sample.bmp , the small bmp file is called Button.bmp . Thing is the when comparing the images the file can't be found anywhere.

the compare code :

```
for (int i=0;i<SCREEN_WIDTH-width;++i)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<SCREEN_HEIGHT-height;++j)
            {
                boolean isequal = true;
                for(int qqq=i;qqq<i+width;++qqq)
                {
                    for (int kkk=j;kkk<j+height;++kkk)
                    {
                        if (PI[qqq][kkk]!=NPI[qqq-i][kkk-j]) isequal = false;
                        if (isequal == false) 
                        {
                                qqq =  i + width + 1;
                                kkk = j + height + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isequal==true)
                {
                    MidX = i;
                    MidY = j;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

note : Screen_width and Screen_height are for the bigger image and width and height are for the smaller one

Full Code:

```
    void readBMP()
{
    int i;
    FILE* f = fopen("Sample.bmp", "rb");
    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];

    int size = 3 * width * height;
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f); // read the rest of the data at once
    fclose(f);

    for(int qq=0;qq<SCREEN_WIDTH;++qq)
        for (int kk=0;kk<SCREEN_HEIGHT;++kk)
        {
            PI[qq][kk][0] = data[kk * width + qq];
            PI[qq][kk][1] = data[kk * width + qq + 1];
            PI[qq][kk][2] = data[kk * width + qq + 2];
        }



}

void FindImageInScreen(char* FileName)
{

    FILE* f = fopen(FileName, "rb");
    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];

    int size = 3 * width * height;
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f); // read the rest of the data at once
    fclose(f);



    for(int qq=0;qq<width;++qq)
        for (int kk=0;kk<height;++kk)
        {
            NPI[qq][kk][0] = data[kk * width + qq];
            NPI[qq][kk][1] = data[kk * width + qq + 1];
            NPI[qq][kk][2] = data[kk * width + qq + 2];
        }

        for (int i=0;i<SCREEN_WIDTH-width;++i)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<SCREEN_HEIGHT-height;++j)
            {
                boolean isequal = true;
                for(int qqq=i;qqq<i+width;++qqq)
                {
                    for (int kkk=j;kkk<j+height;++kkk)
                    {
                        if (PI[qqq][kkk][0]!=NPI[qqq-i][kkk-j][0]) isequal = false;
                        if (isequal == false) 
                        {
                                qqq =  i + width + 1;
                                kkk = j + height + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isequal==true)
                {
                    MidX = i;
                    MidY = j;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        MidX = -1;
        MidY = -1;
        return;

}
```

definition of arrays (added because of request) , This is before functions execute :

```
         PI = new unsigned int**[SCREEN_WIDTH];
    for (int i=0;i<SCREEN_WIDTH;++i)
        PI[i] = new unsigned int*[SCREEN_HEIGHT];
    for (int i=0;i<SCREEN_WIDTH;++i)
        for (int j=0;j<SCREEN_HEIGHT;++j)
            PI[i][j] = new unsigned int[3];


    NPI = new unsigned int**[SCREEN_WIDTH];
    for (int i=0;i<SCREEN_WIDTH;++i)
        NPI[i] = new unsigned int*[SCREEN_HEIGHT];
    for (int i=0;i<SCREEN_WIDTH;++i)
        for (int j=0;j<SCREEN_HEIGHT;++j)
            NPI[i][j] = new unsigned int[3];
```

The First function executes then the second.  and sorry for some bad programming because I did thousands of changes to make it work!

Comment: lets start with the most obvious; scan-line-sizes are 4-byte padded in BMP

Comment: You might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095738/search-for-a-small-image-in-a-big-one/24095988#24095988

Comment: While this is possibly valid C++, it has a heavy `C` smell, the only C++ feature used is the `new` keyword, which makes it unable to be tagged as C. However, when I see such code: `NPI = new unsigned int**[SCREEN_WIDTH];` I feel like running away as fast as possible... Please take a look into modern C++ design and use standard library containers.

Comment: I think I almost found the problem , Think There problem is the reading of the file , when the code goes to the second row (when the first row was completly right) the data don't match. used the 4 bit too but it didn't work , help in reading the file part ?

Comment: Again, as stated in my post which I deleted since you mentioned not being able to change your code. You're reading a 24 bit bitmap as a 32 bit one. You NEED to handle the 4-byte padding.

Comment: The only Thing I changed was    int size = 3 * width * height; ->>>    int size = 4 * width * height; but it didn't work , what other things should I change ? (Will be better if you could help me out cause I'm almost depressed that I can't make a simple program to work.)

Answer (score 0):

```
PI[qq][kk][0] = data[kk * width + qq];
```

From how `PI` and `NPI` are filled in, it appears that they are 3-dimensional arrays (it would help if you included their definition in the code sample). But

```
if (PI[qqq][kkk]!=NPI[qqq-i][kkk-j]) isequal = false;
```

which is only indexing 2 dimensions of each. `PI[a][b]` is the address of the array containing `PI[a][b][0..2]` and will certainly never match the address of `NPI[x][y]`, so this statement is always returning false I expect.

Comment: I accidentally removed that part for asking another person , edited it + added the definition code

Answer (score 0):

Lets get you started. Here is a better LoadBMP.
Yours, among other thing, read the size, and uses SCREEN_HEIGHT anyway.
Using this for loading both images is probably easier.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char UC;

struct RGB { UC r,g,b; };
bool operator == ( const RGB& p1, const RGB& p2 ) { return p1.r==p2.r && p1.g==p2.g && p1.b==p2.b; }

struct BMP
{
    int width;
    int height;
    vector<RGB> pixels;
    RGB& Pix(int x,int y) { return pixels[ y*width + x ]; }
};

void LoadBMP( BMP& bmp, const char* filename )
{
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    UC info[54];
    fread(info, 1, 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    bmp.width =  *(int*) (info+18);
    bmp.height = *(int*) (info+22);

    // scanlines are always multiple of 4, padded with 0-3 bytes
    int scanlinesize = 3*bmp.width;
    while( scanlinesize % 4 ) ++scanlinesize;
    int size = scanlinesize * bmp.height;
    UC* data = new UC[size];
    fread(data, 1, size, f);
    fclose(f);

    bmp.pixels.clear();
    bmp.pixels.reserve(bmp.height*bmp.width);
    for(int yy=0;yy<bmp.height;++yy)
    {
        UC* p = data+scanlinesize*yy;
        for (int xx=0;xx<bmp.width;++xx)
        {
            RGB rgb;
            rgb.b = *p++;
            rgb.g = *p++;
            rgb.r = *p++;
            bmp.pixels.push_back(rgb);
        }
    }
    delete[] data;
}
```